# Entity Framework Code first, relation between models

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Is there someone who will listen to me and help me solve my problem?

I have 3 classes (Product, Lot and Rem):

Each Product has many Lot and each Lot has many Rem.

```
public class Product {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 
}

public class Lot {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; } 
}

public class Rem {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string note  { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to modify these classes to be well connected

Comment: What about a `List<Lot>` as a class member of `Product` as well as a `List<Rem>` as a class member of `Lot`? You would have to implement some `add(Lot lot)` and `remove(Lot lot)` if you are in need of those actions. Same for `Lot` and its `Rem`s...

Comment: From Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you described above this is a simple way for related entities in EF.

```
public class Product {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 

    public Lot LotId {get; set; }
    public ICollection<Lot> Lots { get; set; } 
}

public class Lot {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    public Product ProductId {get; set; }
    public Product Product {get; set; }

    public Rem RemId {get; set; }
    public ICollection<Rem> Rems { get; set; }
}

public class Rem {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string note  { get; set; } 

    public Lot LotId {get; set; }
    public Lot Lot { get; set; } 

}
```

And the dbcontext class

```
public class AppDbContext: DbContext
{
 public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options): base(options)
{
}

public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public DbSet<Lot> Lots { get; set; }
public DbSet<Rem> Rems { get; set; }
}
```

You can find further explanation about relationships in EF from [relationships in EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: Thank you, it's helpful

Comment: Glad to help you @AhBo